# How to serve static files with Angular on AppEngine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine

I use Cloud Build to automatically deploy an Angular app to AppEngine upon push to the master branch of my repo.

cloudbuild.yaml contains the following to build and deploy:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'run', 'build', '--prod' ]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--version=prod']
```

In the CSS code I reference a png:

```
background: url(../assets/img/f3835d65.png) repeat;
```

When I execute the `npm run build --prod` locally, under dist, the original png is kept and a copy is made to the root (first misunderstanding).

Then I tried to declare a handler in app.yaml:

```
handlers:
 - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
   static_files: dist\1
   upload: dist/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

But when the app is built and deploy, when I access the appspot url I receive the following error:

> GET https://[my-project].appspot.com/f3835d65.png 404 /home:18

Also when I go to the "sources" tab in Chrome I cannot find the png...

Any clue why I have this behavior and how I can make this work?

Comment: How does the `assets/img` path you reference relates to the `dist` specification from your `app.yaml` handler? Where's your png file actually located relative to `app.yaml`?

Comment: @DanCornilescu relative to `app.yaml`, the png file is located at `./src/assets/img/` but when building Angular puts the built code into `./dist/moops/` (moops is the name of the project). And after this build I can find `./dist/moops/f3835d65.png` and `./dist/moops/assets/img/f3835d65.png`. All the path I mentioned in this comment are relative to `app.yaml` which is at the root of my project folder.